# android:textisselectable is not working on android 5.0 or greater but working on 4.2

Tags: android, textview, copy

hi i am using `android:textIsSelectable="true"` to enable copy menu feature on text view it is working on android 4.2 jellybean but when trying this on lollipop menu appear for a second and auto disappear.is there any thing that i am missing in xml on i have to add in class file associated with XML

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/singleMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:text="MyMsg"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you app theme extends one of .NoActionBar themes, you need to enable windowActionModeOverlay, to fix this issue.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try, and check the android docs link for details.

```
android:setTextIsSelectable="true"
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextIsSelectable(boolean)

Comment: already go throw it but unable to find the reason why same thing is not working on android os greater then the jelly bean i check on 5.0.2 and 5.1.1 both and its not working

Comment: Check your manifest configuration, it could be something slightly a miss in there.